# how to call the codebehind file methods in java script in asp.net2.0?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i can write methods like that

```
public void CompareEmail()
{
some code
}
public void UpdateEmail()
    {
some code

}
public void InsertEmail()
    {
some code

    }
```

i am click the button onclientclick call the function like that

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnSendNow" runat="server" CssClass="invdisp_btn" OnClick="btnSendNow_Click"
                    Text="Send Now" OnClientClick="return getEmailMessage()" />
```

java script function is like that

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function getEmailMessage()
     {
  var LoginID = document.getElementById('hdn').value;\\ i can pass 1 or 0
        if (LoginID != 0)
        {   
        //This place using CompareEmail() method How to write code comapare values not matching ask update confirm box  
        var ans;
        ans = window.confirm('DO u want to update?'); 

            if (ans == true) 
            {
//                      control.UpdateEmail();\\how to call UpdateMethod in .cs file
                alert('updated');

            }
            else {

                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            var ans;
            ans = window.confirm('DO u want to Insert values?');
            if (ans == true) 
            {
            PageMethods.InsertEmail();\\how to call InsertMethod in .cs file
//            control.InsertEmail();
               alert('Inserted');
            }
            else 
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

how to write the code in java script function call the .cs file methods pls help me

Thank u
hemanth

Comment: Read on for `WebMethod` and [`Ajax`](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=109)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try [Pagemethods and ASP.net Ajax](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by declaring your method as Web Methods in the code behind files.

Have look at this [How to call a server-side method from client-side JavaScript !](http://decoding.wordpress.com/2008/11/14/aspnet-how-to-call-a-server-side-method-from-client-side-javascript/), it completely gives a solution to your problem.

Otherwise you can also use [AJAx](http://www.ajaxpro.info/quickguide.aspx) to do this.

Comment: @Anand Thangappan - Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To call a server side method from client side, you have the following options:

1. Use ICallBackEventHandler
2. Use a Webservice with [ScriptService] attribute and call it's web methods from js
3. Use PageMethods. But that allows you to call static methods on your aspx page, only. Hence you won't be able to access any page controls.

I would recommend option 2, since it's the easiest.